# the best way of passing variable from node to local javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best practice of passing data from node (express.js) to client javascript file? (not to ejs- just normal javascript file).

Example:

1. user type any word to input in page1.html
2. On backend I receive the word an redirect to page2.
3. on this page2 I have attached script (in a separate file)
   The question is how to get the word in the separate javascript file attached to the page2?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve. It's unclear to me if you're trying to pass data from your server to your client, or simply trying to write a file... Please provide more information.

Comment: @GarrettManley I did it

Answer (score 1):

One common way is to insert a script tag into the page that contains the variables you want to set: (As always, cleanse your data to avoid injections)

```
....
<script>
  const myVar = 10; // modified by server, this is the value the user typed
</script>
....
<script> // uses myVar, your code here
  if (myVar == 10) alert(1)
</script>
<script src="myscriptthatusesmyVar.js"></script>
```

Another option is to have the client JS request a special page that has the value as JSON data or something.

However, if you're trying to send lots of things and keep a connection between the server and the client while the user is on the page, I'd check out websockets

Edit: since there's a redirect, you have more options.

Page1:
`https://example.com/page1.html`

Say the user types in "abc123".

You can then redirect the user to `https://example.com/page2.html?v=abc123` and read the query string.

Comment: I can't do thah couse my client javascirpt file is very extensive

Comment: Does the solution I added work for you?

Comment: no, i don't want to have javascript file in <script> tag, just from an other file

Comment: That works too, since global variables can go across files- edited my answer again to show you :)

Comment: okay it works :) but the question is that is something more recomended how to do this

Comment: Unfortunately that's opinion-and-situation-based- I see the script tag injection all the time, and query string stuff is very common if it's a small string